# Remove Directory path from Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am beginner in C and learning it on VS Code. I want to make terminal minimal so I want to remove directory from powershell to make it miinimal like the terminal in sublime.[For reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REiLB.png)
I tried looking it on google but don't know how to word it properly. Thanks

Comment: what you are referring to is the prompt. do a search for `powershell customize prompt` to get the details of how to change it. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I got the result. Thanks.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]